# Cannot Compile Qt 5.2 with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, compilation, compiler-errors

I've been compiling ever release of Qt since 5.0 and it always compiles fine but I am now getting error 2 from jom. Here are the commands I ran:

```
configure -no-opengl -nomake examples -nomake tools -static -release
jom
```

Here is the configure output: http://pastie.org/pastes/8550496/text

Here is the jom output: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/764231/jom.txt

The jom output is so large (1.09 megabytes) that I had to upload the text file to DropBox because pastie only supports a maximum of 64 kilobytes and other competitors only suport 250 kilobytes or similar sizes.

Edit: For some reason, the jom output doesn't cover the end result (error 2), so here's a screenshot: http:/i.stack.imgur.com/2mHkk.png

I can't post an image or more than two links as a new user, so I have removed the second "/" in "http://" from the imgur link.

Comment: Neither of the links has a complete text of even one error message.

Comment: @n.m. For some reason, output redirection using jom didn't catch the "Error 1" and "Error 2" errors I got from jom. I've put a screenshot of the errors.

Comment: Let me try that again. Neither of the links, **including the screenshot**, has a complete text of even one error message. I hope it's clearer now.